# Analyzing data from a non-randomized sampling design (ecological monitoring)

Tags: random-variable, survey-sampling, observational-study, monitoring

I have 2 questions about analyzing data that was not randomly sampled from a population.

I work with "ecological monitoring" data that involves repeatedly taking measurements from the same location of interest, as well as from nearby locations as a reference, for the purposes of monitoring change in the ecosystem. There is no "treatment", everything is observational and measured once per site from the same sites, twice a year, every year (Fish counts: patchy count data with many zeros; and salinity and temperature readings). I don't see evidence to suggest any of the variables come from a normal distribution, nor does transforming the data work. The goal is to model fish occurrence (0 = absent, 1 = present) using these variables.

My questions:

1. My colleague suggests treating "location" as a random variable in a logistic regression model but the sampling method is not random, so why would treating it as random work?, and
2. If it should be a random variable, what are the things to keep in-mind when making inferences from the result, given the nature of which the data was collected? As I understand it, inferences should be restricted to just these locations because of some possible bias in their location selection.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you have worded your first question, I suspect it is the wrong interpretation of the term "random" when referring to a variable in a regression model.

1. Defining a variable as "random" in a regression model (reffered to as random effects) does not refer to the randomness of sampling, but rather the random variation across locations. By treating location as a random variable, you can explore the "fixed" effects (i.e. salinity, temperature) whilst recognising that repeated samples at one location are not independent of each other.
2. Defining location as a random effect allows you to generalise results across locations (ignoring the effect of location), and extrapolate estimates of other fixed effects to new locations. These inferences assume all locations vary randomly from a overall mean. Here it is important to consider if your locations are representative of the environment. Whilst random sampling is desirable, such studies can use expert judgement to choose locations, or select them systematically.

Further reading on modelling random effects in an ecological context include [Bolker et al. (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tree.2008.10.008) and [Harrison et al. 2018](https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.4794)

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your answer. Just one clarification: I had learned that only random sampling allows for results to be generalized to other locations/sites and conclusions from fixed sites can only be applied to those fixed sites. If an environment of interest doesn't vary much in terms of the variables measured, then I can see generalizing to other new sites, but we don't know if our sites are representative of the environment - our finite number of sites are more due to budget constraints, so would you say we shouldn't extrapolate our results to the broader environment?

Comment: It's possible to generalise with nonrandom sampling of sites (e.g. systematic sampling or expert judgement). There's also the example of using commercial fisheries data to generalise about fish populations. It's difficult to answer in the context of your study, but if you can't evaluate the representativeness then you're right that you should model them as fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Summarized answer I got from other colleagues:

Proceed with the analysis as if it were randomly selected, but clearly state the data collection method, be it haphazard or random...

Comment: You can do better.  Good resources--classics in the field--include Steven Thompson's *Sampling* and Richard Gilbert's *Statistical Methods for Environmental Pollution Monitoring.*